# Brumer quintic polynomials - is there a general formula for the roots?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots, irreducible-polynomials

There exist a family of quintic polynomials, called Brumer's polynomials (or Kondo-Brumer), which have the form:

$$x^5+(a-3)x^4+(-a+b+3)x^3+(a^2-a-1-2b)x^2+bx+a,~~~a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$$

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function) these polynomials are solvable in radicals.

> Is there a general formula for roots of these polynomials? Or at least the closed form for some special cases?

I searched the web, but only found papers discussing the group properties (for example [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.0054)) or other properties of Brumer's polynomials. Nothing about the roots.

**Edit**

I'm starting a bounty, and I would like either of these things:

- General solution (at least one root), depending on $a,b$ - only if such a solution exists, and is short enough to write here in closed form.
- Some methods for obtaining this solution - again, if it will lead to a form of the solution more compact and simpler than the general way to solve an arbitrary solvable quintic.
- Solutions to some special cases (for some values of $a,b$ with $b \neq 0$)
- A proof that no such simple solution is possible for this family of quintics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the solvable ***Kondo-Brumer quintic***,

$$x^5 + (a - 3)x^4 + (-a + b + 3)x^3 + (a^2 - a - 1 - 2b)x^2 + b x + a = 0\tag1$$

One in fact can make explicit formulas for these. For simplicity, assume $a=1$, so

> $$x^5 - 2x^4 + (b + 2)x^3 + (-1 - 2b)x^2 + b x + 1=0\tag2$$

Define the four roots $z_i$ of its quartic *Lagrange resolvent*,

$$z^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\big((597 + 225 b + 200 b^2) \color{blue}+ 5\sqrt{5} (43 + 33 b + 20 b^2)\big)z +{c_1}^5=0\tag3$$

$$z^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}\big((597 + 225 b + 200 b^2) \color{blue}- 5\sqrt{5} (43 + 33 b + 20 b^2)\big)z +{c_2}^5=0\tag4$$

which was factored into two quadratics for convenience, and,

$$c_1=-\tfrac{1}{2}\big((2+5b)\color{blue}-\sqrt{5}(4-b)\big)\tag5$$
$$c_2=-\tfrac{1}{2}\big((2+5b)\color{blue}+\sqrt{5}(4-b)\big)\tag6$$

Note the constant term of the quartic is a nice fifth power,

$$(c_1 c_2)^5=(5b^2+15b-19)^5$$

We can then give the relatively "simple" solution,

$$x =  \frac{1}{5}\Big(2+z_1^{1/5}+z_2^{1/5}+z_3^{1/5}+z_4^{1/5}\Big)\tag7$$

> **Example:** Let $b=-1$, then,

$$x^5 - 2x^4 + x^3 + x^2 - x + 1=0$$

a quintic which was also solved by Ramanujan. Its resolvent using $(3),(4)$ is,

$$z^4 + 572z^3 + 70444z^2 + 1600203z - 29^5=0$$

then,

$$x= \frac{1}{5}\Big(2+z_1^{1/5}+z_2^{1/5}+z_3^{1/5}+z_4^{1/5}\Big) = -0.90879\dots$$

If all the $z_i$ are real, as in the example, then it is a simple matter of taking fifth roots of real numbers which will then yield a real root of the quintic.

Comment: I've seen the first case in some old mathforum discussion. I think you were there as well. So, no such simple solution for the general $a$? I've also seen your paper on sextic resolvents and I have a question - how do we guess the roots, such that their squares are rational?

Comment: @YuriyS: Do you really want the formula for general $a$, or would you rather know a simple method to solve the solvable quintic? That way, you'll be able to deal with any new quintics yourself. If so, ask a question on "how to solve the solvable quintic using its quartic lagrange resolvents" and I'll gladly answer it.

Comment: Tito, no thank you. 'Simple' is a relative word. I'm collecting parametric solvable quintics with relatively short solutions, which can be easily written in closed form. Think De Moivre quintic. I've found several, but the search continues.

Comment: @YuriyS: Ok, I have a collection of my own. Another famous one is the Emma Lehmer quintic. Do you have it already?

Comment: Ttio, no this is the first time I've heard of it. I've found several papers now, including Spearman Williams paper. It relates four roots to one root. But I don't see a formula for the one root. And another case [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.research/Q1PdZ6_uS1Y) Thank you for mentioning it.

Comment: @YuriyS: I've added another answer re the general family to which the Lehmer quintic belongs to.

Answer (score 2):

The roots of any (irreducible) solvable quintic can be found, using methods due to George Paxton Young in 1888. An explicit 3-page formula based on those methods was given by Daniel Lazard in 2004. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function

Comment: I'm aware. I meant an easier formula for this special case, like for De Moivre quintic

Comment: @YuriyS: I imagine it's possible to deduce a somewhat simpler formula for the Brumer quintic from the general formula for solvable quintics, but it's likely still very complicated, and the aforementioned derivation is presumably a very nontrivial application of Galois Theory.

Comment: @JustinBenfield: The Brumer quintic has two free parameters. If, for convenience, we suppress one parameter, then yes it is possible to find a rather simple formula. Kindly see other answer for this post.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Since the formula is not homogeneous, suppressing one parameter is not just a "convenience", it is a loss of generality (unless I missed something)

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Yes, it is a loss of generality. However, I should have added that assuming $a=1$ (or any value) is an illustrative example, as the formulas for $a=0,1,2,3,\dots$ are very similar in form. I could have used general $a$, but the poster did mention particular cases would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

(*Addendum to my answer*.) Since the primary objective of the OP is to find solvable quintics with a "simple" solution, then we can add the "*depressed*" multi-parameter family,

$y^5+10cy^3+10dy^2+5ey+f = 0\tag{1}$

where the coefficients obey the quadratic in $f$,

$(c^3 + d^2 - c e) \big((5 c^2 - e)^2 + 16 c d^2\big) = (c^2 d + d e - c f)^2
\tag{2}$

Solve for $f$. Define this quintic's *Lagrange resolvent* as,

$$(z^2+u_1z-c^{5})(z^2+u_2z-c^{5}) = 0$$

where the $u_i$ are the two roots of the quadratic,

$$u^2-fu+(4c^5-5c^3e-4d^2e+ce^2+2cdf) = 0$$

then the solution to $(1)$ is,

$y = z_1^{1/5}+z_2^{1/5}+z_3^{1/5}+z_4^{1/5}\tag{3}$

Note that appropriate choices of the $3$ free parameters $c,d,e$ can yield rational $f$.

> **Example**: A particular case is the ***Lehmer quintic***,

$$x^5 + n^2x^4 - (2n^3 + 6n^2 + 10n + 10)x^3 + (n^4 + 5n^3 + 11n^2 + 15n + 5)x^2 + (n^3 + 4n^2 + 10n + 10)x + 1=0$$

Let $x = (y-n^2)/5$ to transform it to depressed form $(1)$. Its transformed coefficients then obey $(2)$.